# reduce many || operators to one statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I am currently validating a form and checking to ensure that the input boxes are not empty. To do this I am using the `app.validation.empty()` method defined below. In my `if` statement there is a lot of repetition. How could I put the following into

```
if(!app.validation.empty(contestName) || !app.validation.empty(date) ||!app.validation.empty(month) ||!app.validation.empty(year) || !app.validation.empty(countryName) || !app.validation.empty(userName) || !app.validation.empty(userLastName))
```

into one method and hence reduce to one statement?

Comment: Uh, it already *is* only one statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `app.validation.empty` as callback with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
if (![contestName, date, month, year, countryName, userName, userLastName]
    .every(app.validation.empty)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** with [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in latest browsers

```
if ([contestName, date, month, year, countryName, userName, userLastName].some((v) => !app.validation.empty(v)))
```

---

You can even avoid the variable

```
app.sendForm = {
    init: function(){    
        $("#entry").submit(function( event ) {
            if(if (["#email","#first_name","#last_name","#birth_day","#birth_month","#birth_year","#contest1_name","#country",'#privacy_check'].some((v) => !app.validation.empty($(v))))){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("There are errors with your form.");
            } else {
                alert("You have entered the competition.");
            }      
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: You even might want to drop the many variables and put the ids in the array.

Comment: @Bergi is this comment directed at me or Pranav?

Comment: @phantom any of you :-)